# I am getting exception on a post request logged in stackify but not able to find cause of the error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, defaultmodelbinder

Following is the exception stackify shows me on dashboard:

ERROR The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0. ---> System.FormatException: null is not a valid value for DateTime.
  at System.DateTimeParse.Parse
  at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom
  at System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter.ConvertFrom
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder.BindModelAsync

I am not able to understand which field of the viewmodel causes the issue like this. How can I catch this exception on my local code?

Comment: You'd better show necessary code to reproduce your problem.The error explains that ` string was not recognized as a valid DateTime` you need to check the DateTime type field in your model binding.

Comment: Actually this error I got from stackify, so I just asked devops to turn on stackify postdata for the request so that I can view the data being sent in the request. After that it would be easy to solve this issue because this issue is due to data being sent